# Ionic 4. How change header background color on old android versions

Tags: ionic-framework

I tried to use css variables for this

```
ion-toolbar {
  --background: #{$backgroundColor3};
  --min-height: #{$spacing * 5};
}
```

All works correct in latest chrome and on android 8. But on adnroid 5 with chrome 40.* it is not worked.

I found that minimal android version for Ionic is 4.4 [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/browser-support)

```
>ionic info
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.0.1
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.4.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0, ios 5.0.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.0, (and 9 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.3.0
   native-run  : 0.2.5

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Android)
   NodeJS            : v11.14.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.9.0
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Background is only one problem with styles:

Screenshot with issues from android 5

[image: Screenshot with issues from android 5]

Normal screenshot

[image: Normal screenshot]

Comment: Do you remember how you solved the problem with older Android versions? I'm facing the same problem. Maybe your problem is related to this issue: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/17781

Answer (score 0):

You need to be use add in global or page .scss file

```
--background: var(--ion-color-primary);
```

Here your answare.

Comment: I tried to use css variables for this

ion-toolbar {
  --background: #{$backgroundColor3};
  --min-height: #{$spacing * 5};
}
All works correct in latest chrome and on android 8. But on adnroid 5 with chrome 40.* it is not worked.